# How do I maintain page model class variables for the duration of the user's session?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I can successfully execute server-side code through HTTP requests in ASP .NET Core but I am unable to store information in the model between requests.

I hoped that switching from a private variable to a service created through ASP NET Core's dependency injection framework would solve my problem but alas it did not.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Earley_Parser.Language;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.RazorPages;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ViewFeatures;

namespace Storyteller.Pages.EarleyParser {
    public class IndexModel : PageModel {
        public readonly IGrammar _grammarContext;

        public IndexModel(IGrammar grammarContext) {
            _grammarContext = grammarContext;
        }

        [HttpGet]
        public IActionResult OnGet() {
            _grammarContext.Add(new GrammarRule("", "S"));
            _grammarContext.Add(new GrammarRule("A", "S"));
            _grammarContext.Add(new GrammarRule("AA", "A"));
            _grammarContext.Add(new GrammarRule("a", "A"));
            return Page();
        }

        [HttpPost]
        public IActionResult OnPostAdd(String grammar_addRule_from, String grammar_addRule_to) {
            _grammarContext.Add(new GrammarRule(grammar_addRule_to, grammar_addRule_from));

            return new PartialViewResult {
                ViewName = "_ContextFreeGrammar",
                ViewData = new ViewDataDictionary<Grammar_2>(ViewData, _grammarContext)
            };
        }

        [HttpPost]
        public IActionResult OnPostRemove(Int32 id) {
            _grammarContext.Remove(_grammarContext.ElementAt(id));

            return new PartialViewResult {
                ViewName = "_ContextFreeGrammar",
                ViewData = new ViewDataDictionary<Grammar_2>(ViewData, _grammarContext)
            };
        }

        [HttpPost]
        public IActionResult OnPostUpdateStart(Char grammar_start) {
            _grammarContext.Start = grammar_start;

            return new PartialViewResult {
                ViewName = "_ContextFreeGrammar",
                ViewData = new ViewDataDictionary<Grammar_2>(ViewData, _grammarContext)
            };
        }
    }
}
```

My ideal scenario is that when the page is loaded, _grammarContext is initialised and subsequent HTTP requests change the state of _grammarContext. This scenario **actually does occur** however, before any HTTP request is executed,

```
IndexModel(IGrammar grammarContext)
```

is called and _grammarContext gets its state reset through dependency injection. How can I stop this reset from occurring?

Comment: Web applications are inherently stateless, that is the nature of the HTTP protocol. If you want to keep your data between requests then you need to save it somewhere permanent (e.g. database) or semi-permanent (e.g. Session), depending on your exact requirements. And then on the next request where you need that data, you load it from the storage into your object.

Comment: Depending on the type of the data, one option is to maintain state on the client side. When the client first receives the data it could store it in the page (if subsequent requests are made from that page) or in the browser's session storage. Then when the user makes requests the data is sent back as part of the request (much like a cookie.) Or, as mentioned, you could store data somewhere (like a database) in between requests.

Comment: Please read about [session and app state in the official documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/app-state?view=aspnetcore-2.2).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would need to register your service with a singleton lifetime:

```
services.AddSingleton<IGrammarContext, GrammarContext>();
```

That way, only one instance will be created for the life of the application, and that same instance will be injected every time.

That said, using a singleton lifetime should be avoided. Since your class here is very basic, only managing an in-memory list, it's not too problematic, but in more advanced scenarios, using singletons can bind you up and encourage other bad practices such as service-locator.